# How to cancel an accidental AdSense click with Google?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, advertising, clicks

My computer decided to be stupid again. It seems when I do some action, the mouse pointer goes wild and random clicks happen, but then again my software could be bad as well.

The point is, when I was investigating, it turned out I (unintentionally) clicked on an ad on my site and a new window opened in the background. Now I need to know how to declare this click as a true accident and refund the advertiser.

What can I do?

Comment: I have no idea. I am paranoid. I do not have ads showing when I view my site... so I have two sets of templates - one with ads and one without ads. I just switch them before mucking about then switch them back. Important question though!

Comment: I did read on google help pages that I shouldn't worry but I feel I need a box on google to type into to declare myself guilty.

Comment: I have said before it would help G to have a way of our giving comments from time to time... call it a *Ooopppssss 5h17! Sorry. I goofed.* page within GWMT. This would go a long way to solving some issues. For now, I suggest a few Hail Mary's and lighting a candle. BTW- I am not Catholic so I have no real idea.

Comment: You can't do anything about it. Just hope their system do not register those clicks as fraud. Sometimes they catch single click and suspend accounts but sometimes, you can get away with several clicks.Make sure this will never happen again.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you need to do. At the end of the billing cycle they will take it out based on their own criteria. See example below:

[image: Adsense Invalid Traffic]

Its the line item called "**Invalid Traffic**" that I highlighted in green. These statements can be found under Payments menu item.

Keep in mind that if this happens often and with substantial amount of clicks your account might get closed.